# Integration of a function in Schwartz space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, schwartz-space

How to prove the following: If $f(x)$ belongs to Schwartz space then integral from $x$ to infinity of $f(x)$ also belongs to Schwartz space?

Comment: Can you write the definition of a Schwartz space?

Comment: this question (or very similar) was posted a couple of days ago. The answer is that it is not true, unless $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=0$. If $I(x)$ is your integral, we certainly need $I(x)\to0$ if $x\to-\infty$ if we want $I(x)\in\mathscr S$. (An example where it fails is thus $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$.)

Answer (score 4):

Let $F(x) = \int_x^\infty f(t)\,dt$. In order to have $F(-\infty)=0$, we must assume $\int_{\mathbb R}f(t)\,dt=0$.  (As user8268 remarked.) Under this assumption, $F$ is indeed a test function in the Schwartz space. The smoothness is clear from $F'=-f$. The decay at $+\infty$ follows from 
$$|F(x)| \le \int_x^\infty C(n)\, t^{-n}\,dt = O(x^{1-n})$$
where $n$ can be arbitrarily large (the first inequality holds because $f$ is a test function).  The decay at $-\infty$ follows similarly, by using $F(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt$:
$$|F(x)|  \le \int_{-\infty}^x C(n)\, |t|^{-n}\,dt = O(|x|^{1-n})$$

Comment: If we let x bigger than 0 or equals to 0?  Can you write some more details to the proof?

Comment: When $x\to-\infty$, we need to consider only negative $x$. When $x\to\infty$, we consider only positive $x$. No need to worry about $0$. As for the number of details... it already exceeds the number of details in your question.

Comment: What does it mean  "it already exceeds the number of details in your question"